# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object in ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object in ajax call

I am using Thymeleaf and Spring MVC and I am having some problems with a dynamic form. 
I have a form with a selector, and when this changed, I do an Ajax call, which should show another selector and a field.

I have these objects:

```
 public class SaleMini{
    private int businessId;
    private int sellerId;
    private int productId;
    private int amount;
    private int row;
    private String date;
    private List<SaleItem> item;
   //getters and setters
}

public class SaleItem{
   private int productId;
   private int amount;
   private boolean gift;
   private List<Integer> components;
   private List<Composition> compositionList;   
  //getters and setters
```

}

My html code is:

```
<form id="sales" action="#" th:action="@{/sales/add}" method="post">                    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label class="label-control" th:text="#{label.equipment}"></label>
        <select th:field="${sales.businessId}" class="form-control"   onchange="submitData()"> <!--- Equipment List --->
            <option th:each="e : ${equipmentList}" th:value="${e.id}" th:text="${e.name}"></option>
        </select>
    </div>

       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
         <label class="label-control" th:text="#{label.seller}"></label>
         <select th:field="${sales.sellerId}" class="form-control">
            <option th:each="s : ${sellerList}" th:value="${s.id}" th:text="${s.name + ' ' + s.surname}"></option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div id="product-panel" class="row" >
     <div th:fragment="resultsList">
        <div th:each="i,rowStat : ${itemList}">
            <p th:text="${i.productId}"></p>
                <select class="form-control products_select" th:field="${i.productId}" th:onchange="${'javascript:callComposed(' + rowStat.index  + ')'}" > 
                    <option value="0" >Select Product</option>
                    <option th:each="p : ${productList}" th:value="${p.id}" th:text="${p.name}" th:attr="data-compound=${p.compound},data-generic=${p.genericId}"></option>
                </select>
          </div>
          <a class="btn btn-action" id="btn-add"  onclick="submitData()" style="margin-top: 25px !important;"><span class="fa fa-plus fa-btn"></span></a> <!--I should add as many product as I wanted-->
    </div>                      
   </div>

   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-btn">
        <input type="submit" th:value="#{label.save.sale}" class="btn btn-custom"/>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

When the Equipment List is change, I do an ajax call

```
function submitData(){
 $.ajax({
    'url':  'sales/addRow',
    'type': 'POST',
    'data': $('#sales').serialize(),
    'success': function(result){
         $("#product-panel" ).html( result );
    },
 });
}
```

The function I call on the controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addRow", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addRow(@Valid SaleMini sale, BindingResult bindingResult,ModelMap model) {    

    List<SaleItem> siList = new ArrayList<SaleItem>();

    if(sale!=null && sale.getBusinessId()!=0)
    {
        SaleItem si = new SaleItem();
        si.setAmount(1);
        siList.add(si);

    }
    model.addAttribute("itemList", siList);
    return folder+"/add :: resultsList";
}
```

The problem is when I call to submitData().

I can do the call to the controller well (submitData() and then addRow), and it works, but when I get the data I have and error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'i' available as request attribute
I get data after the call, but I can't access to the data with th:field

In the html part this works (th:text):

```
<p th:text="${i.productId}"></p>
```

But this not (th:field), and I don't know why:

```
<select class="form-control products_select" th:field="${i.productId}" th:onchange="${'javascript:callComposed(' + rowStat.index  + ')'}" > 
</select>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you are missing a couple of details in your form. With this **th:object="sale"** you say what will be the modelAttribute of your form, and to make reference to any attribute of that object just use ***{attribute.path}**

```
<form id="sales" action="#" th:action="@{/sales/add}" method="post" th:object="sale">
```

And to make reference to attributes of your sale object use:

```
<select th:field="*{businessId}" class="form-control"   onchange="submitData()"> <!--- Equipment List --->
        <option th:each="e : ${equipmentList}" th:value="${e.id}" th:text="${e.name}"></option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried that , and it is the same if I use th:object and then I use * or without th:object and $